# webRTC - connecting 2 clients on same network

Tags: javascript, webrtc, candidate

I made a browser chat which sends the offer and answer of the "RTCPeerConnection" by a web-socket server which closes after the transmition (it works).

I would like to make an app which connects only when the 2 clients are on the same localhost/router (no server) and would like to know if it is possible to do any of the next actions:

1. set default port for ICEcandidate (to be able to easily search for
   the port).
2. make a broadcast to all the possible ports with the offer so i could find the next client.
3. make some static connection with webRTC with predifined settings.

If i gave too much of a broad description please tell.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this would require customization in the ICE/STUN server implementation.  Will your ICE server always be within the same network as well or could it also be external?

Comment: My idea is to make it so 2 people will connect on the same network, just so it won't need any STUN server to send the credentials, and again i am trying to do it serverless.